# laravel 5 template changes doesn't show

Tags: apache, caching, laravel-5

I just started learning laravel 5, and have one running on an amazon web service EC2 instance.  On the EC2 instance, I have Centos 7 with the lamp stack installed.  I configure laravel to work with apache virtual host (I have other virtual hosted sites running which do not use laravel).  My laravel website is fine, but some of the blade template doesn't show changes on the browser when i make changes to them.  Only some of the templates have this problem.  I tried `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan route:clear` but it doesn't do anything.  Anyone have the same problem and have a fix?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some more research i was able to solve the problem.  I solved it by going into the storage/framework/view and delete all files in the directory except the .gitignore file